# Insertion in a doubly linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, logic, doubly-linked-list

My program keeps on crashing. I think there's a problem in my logic. Please help! Thanks!

```
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *prev,*next;
} *head = NULL;


void insert(){
    struct node* temp = (struct node*) malloc (sizeof (struct node*));
    int value;
    printf("Enter an element");
    scanf("%d",&value);
    temp -> data = value;
    temp -> next = NULL;
    temp -> prev = NULL;
    if(value < head -> data || head == NULL){
        temp -> next = head -> next;
        head = temp;
        return;
    }
    while(head->next != NULL && value > head -> next -> data)
        head = head -> next;
    temp -> next = head ->next->prev;
    head -> next = temp -> prev;
    while (head -> prev != NULL)
        head = head -> prev;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *prev,*next;
} *head = 0;


void insert(int value){
    struct node* temp = (struct node*) malloc (sizeof (struct node));
    //int value;
    //printf("Enter an element");
    //scanf("%d",&value);
    temp -> data = value;
    temp -> next = 0;
    temp -> prev = 0;
    if(head == 0) {
        // no head, make temp the head
        head = temp;
    } else if(value > head->data) {
        // put temp in front of the head
        temp->next = head;
        head->prev = temp;
        head = temp;
    } else {
        // put temp after the head
        struct node *this = head;
        struct node *prev = 0;
        while(this && this->data > value) {
            prev = this;
            this = this->next;
        }
        temp->next = this;
        temp->prev = prev;
        prev->next = temp;
        if(this) {
            this->prev = temp;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    insert(1);
    insert(3);
    insert(4);
    struct node *t = 0;
    for(t = head; t; t = t->next) {
        printf("%d\n", t->data);
    }
}
```

This one compiles and sorts in descending value. Note I commented out your scanf
and made insert take a parameter.

Comment: No. You only need to allocate the "temp" variable.

Comment: Thanks! I just had to change 'this' pointer to 'that' and it worked! Oh and I also commented out the 'head->prev = temp;' line.

Comment: If you like my answer you can upvote or accept it. That way I get some points! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

the space you malloc is not enough.

change

```
struct node* temp = (struct node*) malloc (sizeof (struct node*));
```

to

```
struct node* temp = (struct node*) malloc (sizeof (struct node));
```

Comment: In fact just: `struct node* temp =  malloc (sizeof struct node);` is best

Answer (score 4):

As a start, think about these two lines and what happens if `head == NULL`:

```
if(value < head->data || head == NULL){
    temp->next = head->next;
```

Specifically what is `head->next`?

Comment: Should I change it to temp -> next = head;?

Comment: @Shail Yes, that would be a good start. That would cause `temp->next` (the new head) to point to the old head or `NULL`, which makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

There are two core problems I see.

1. You are not allocating sufficient space for a node struct. `sizeof(struct node *)` returns the size of a node pointer, not a node. This:

   ```
   struct node* temp = (struct node*) malloc (sizeof (struct node*));`
   ```

   ... should be this:

   ```
   struct node* temp = (struct node*) malloc (sizeof (struct node));
   ```
2. Be careful with pointers:

   ```
    if (value < head -> data || head == NULL)
   ```

   ... what is the value of `head->data` if you haven't initialized `head`? (e.g. it is still `NULL`). Your program will fetch data from address `NULL` with an offset for field `data`. Address `NULL` is not valid / is part of protected memory space, your OS won't like this :).

You should first check if `head` is `NULL`. If it is, then you can't reference fields of `head` as they are invalid (in any situation). Be careful with multi-part conditional expressions to check for struct pointer `NULL` presence prior to subsequent parts that reference struct fields, also.